# Открыть балун метки в менеджере объектов при наведении (по ховеру)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность  реализовать открытие балуна при наведении? https://jsfiddle.net/bw4u0kny/

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init () {

  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.76, 37.64],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: ['zoomControl']
  }, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
  }),
      objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
        clusterize: true,
        // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
        gridSize: 32,
        clusterDisableClickZoom: false
      });

  // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
  // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
  objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#blueDotIcon');
  objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#redClusterIcons');
  myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    objectManager.add(data);
}

var data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "options": {"preset": "islands#orangeIcon"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.736600, 37.621479]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<b>1</b>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Россия, Москва, улица Большая Ордынка, 40с4</p>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "options": {"preset": "islands#blueIcon"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.736479, 37.621409]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3>2</font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Россия, Москва, улица Большая Ордынка, 40с4</p>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 2, "options": {"preset": "islands#blueIcon"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.791258, 37.635206]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3>3</font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>г. Москва, Проспект Мира, д.78</p>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 3, "options": {"preset": "islands#blueIcon"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.784400, 37.662282]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3>4</font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>г. Москва, Верхняя Красносельская, д.11А, стр. 1</p>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 4, "options": {"preset": "islands#blueIcon"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.650511, 37.745925]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3>5</font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>г. Москва, ул. Люблинская, д.165</p>"}}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно слушать событие наведения курсора на объектах в менеджере и по нему вызывать открытие балуна на объекте:

```
  objectManager.objects.events.add('mouseenter', function(e){
    var obj = e.get('objectId');
    objectManager.objects.balloon.open(obj);
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bw4u0kny/1/

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Добавлена возможность закрытия balloon при mouseleave - https://jsfiddle.net/bw4u0kny/2/

Comment: Если по mouseleave балун должен скрываться, нужно использовать hint - они так работают из коробки и даже события отслеживать не нужно) 
В [этом примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager) так сделано